# Linear recursion with constant coefficients that fullfil $a_n = 3^n + 7^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Let $a_n = 3^n + 7^n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$

I know that the generating function of $a_n= 3^n+7^n = A(x) = \frac{1}{1 - 3x} + \frac{1}{1 - 7x}.$

The exponential generating function

$$A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}x^n$$

of the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is

$A(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^n}{n!}x^n+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{7^n}{n!}x^n= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(3x)^n}{n!}+ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(7x)^n}{n!}=e^{3x}+e^{7x}.$

I want to find out a linear recursion with constant coefficients, that fullfil $a_n$, but I don't know how its done

Comment: $$a_n=10a_{n-1}-21a_{n-2}$$

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: $(r-3)(r-7)=r^2-10r+21$ is a quadratic with zeroes $r=3$ and $r=7$.

Comment: Alternatively, the first four values of $3^n+7^n$ are $2,10,58,370$, so you could just solve the linear equations $58=10A+2B$ and $370=58A+10B$ for the coefficients $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: And the approach works for every $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^Kn^{i_k}(r_k)^n$$ yielding a recursion of length $$K+\sum_{k=1}^Ki_k$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_n-3^n = 7^n$$

so $$ a_{n+1}-3^{n+1}= 7^{n+1}$$

so $$a_{n+1}-3^{n+1}=7\cdot 7^n = 7(a_n-3^n )$$

so $$a_{n+1}-7a_n = -4\cdot 3^n$$

so  $$a_{n+2}-7a_{n+1} = -4\cdot 3^{n+1}$$ $$=-12\cdot 3^n$$ $$= 3(-4\cdot 3^n)$$
$$ =3 (a_{n+1}-7a_n )$$

So $$a_{n+2}-10a_{n+1} +21a_n =0$$

Comment: Of course, making this hands-on approach work for, say, $a_n=2^n+3^n+7^n+9^n$ would be a pain in the you-know-what, although adding a tiny bit of theory would completely trivialize the task (see comments on main).